# Angular: How to get text from all elements and there descendants?

Tags: angular

In AngularJS this was straightforward. We could use the [angular.element().text()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) function which essentially just uses the [jQuery .text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to:

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.

This is exactly what I want to replicate in Angular (v6), but I have been unable to locate any methods in their documentation that replace this functionality. Additionally I would really like to avoid loading jQuery just for this one use case.

In the legacy AngularJS client I have code like this:

```
// Note: This html is actually coming from a server
var html = `<div>
              <span>Record final amount added to productA </span>
              <input ...>
              <br>
              <span >ProductA</span>: <span> Max Capacity 2500 kg</span>
              <span> Continue process for sequence B </span>
            </div>`;

var allText = angular.element(html).text();
```

**Is there a replacement method in Angular to accomplish this or is there some new established pattern of doing it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. If you want the innerText from DOM**

Use `@ViewChild` for this

Add a template variable on the div you want the text from.

`<div #myDiv>This is the text in this div</div>`

Then in your Component Class, create a variable and decorate it with the `@ViewChild` decorator by importing it first from `@angular/core`.

`@ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef;`

This will yield you the inner text.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.myDiv.nativeElement.innerText
}
```

**2. If you only want to get the inner text without the HTML Tags**

In your TypeScript just use this regex:

`html.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');`

Comment: Thank you for your response. This solution will not work, because I don't inject the HTML from the server into the DOM. So I won't be able to add a template variable to it and get it's innerText after being rendered in the view. I need to get the text from the HTML while still in the logic of the component.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: The short version - the HTML I get comes from a different client and the inner text contains valuable information that I need to get. I then can parse and filter the text for later use. However, all the HTML and infinite variations of HTML attributes and tags is too much to deal with to justify parsing all of it instead of just collecting all the inner text. The solution in the AngularJS client was so simple and clean - I am hoping there is a similar solution in Angular.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you for your time and help!